# Maximum length of headers

Tags: email, mime, rfc

I am interested in the maximum length of the header name, header value.
And are there any restrictions on the maximum number of parameters?

Comment: [RFC 2822](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2822) seems to be the relevant standard, but as far as I can see it doesn't explicitly address either of these limits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of the relevant specifications define a maximum length for a header name or value, *but* [rfc5321 section 4.5.3.1.6](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5321#section-4.5.3.1.6) states that the maximum line length is 1000 octets (aka 1000 bytes) including the terminating <CR><LF> sequence.

How does that affect maximum header name/value lengths, you might ask?

It doesn't affect the maximum header *value* length at all because [rfc5322 section 3.2.2](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5322#section-3.2.2) defines CFWS (**C**omment **F**olding **W**hite**S**pace) which is further used in the BNF grammar definitions for headers, which basically allows header *values* to be infinite in length.

That said, while there is no *explicit* maximum length for a header field *name*, there *is* a practical one.

- The maximum line length is 1000 octets (including the terminating <CR><LF> sequence).
- The *recommended* maximum line length is 78 octets (see [rfc5322 section 2.1.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5322#section-2.1.1)).
- The syntactical definition of a header looks like this:
  `optional-field  =   field-name ":" unstructured CRLF`
  `field-name      =   1*ftext`
  `ftext           =   %d33-57 /          ; Printable US-ASCII`
                      `%d59-126           ;  characters not including`
                                         `;  ":".`
  (where `optional-field` is any header field that is not pre-defined in the specification such as "To", "From", "Date", "Subject", etc). This syntax definition can be found in [rfc5322 section 3.6.8](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5322#section-3.6.8).
- Header field names *cannot* be folded (as seen by the syntax definition).

Since it must be possible to represent a header field name *and* the colon (":") all within 998 bytes (1000 bytes minus the <CR><LF> sequence), we can safely conclude that the maximum length of a header field name is 997 bytes (or, since header field names are constrained to US-ASCII, **997** *characters*) and *SHOULD* be constrained to fit within a recommended maximum line length of 78 bytes, meaning the maximum header field name *SHOULD* be a maximum of **77** bytes/characters.